# NPM unmet dependency: how to exactly see what package and version is causing this dependency?

Tags: npm, npm-install

i was running

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@1.14.0 extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 babel-loader css-loader file-loader de-sass sass-loader style-loader url-loader webpack babel-core
```

the problem is there, it *needs* to be webpack 1.14. It cannot be any newer because of incompatible changes.

Now when running it I get

```
├─┬ url-loader@0.5.9 
│ └── mime@1.3.6 
└─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.2.0
  ├── acorn@5.1.1 
  ├─┬ acorn-dynamic-import@2.0.2 
  │ └── acorn@4.0.13 
  ├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY ajv@5.2.2
```

In the package json is finally:

```
{
  "name": "lektor-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

and the app doesn't run because somethign requires a newer webpack version. Now how can I figure out *WHAT* is asking for that webpack version? because I can ask for an older version of said package easily, when I know which version and package is causing the problem. Why is NPM not telling me that?

something else I can do to figure it out?

github issue:

https://github.com/lektor/lektor-webpack-support/issues/14